# How to make select query to select data from one table and results give to another select

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to make table in HTML. First column should be names of people and next columns should be date of lessons. I would like to make something like school attendance. When someone was in class the cell should be green when I click on it otherwise it should be white.
I want to select names of users and names of lessons from database. How shoul I write good select query that can do what i want?

> SCHEME OF TABLE USERS:
>   -**id** (tinyint)
>   -**name** (varchar)
>   -**password** (varchar) md5
>
> SCHEME OF TABLE LESSONS:
>   -**id** (tinyint)
>   -**name** (date)

I make an example of data that I want to get:

http://jsfiddle.net/k8UgT/207/

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>25.10.</th>
        <th>26.10.</th>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Jack</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sam</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JQUERY:

```
$( function() {
  $('td').click( function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
} )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a new table, let's say `users_lessons_date` with the following structure:

- id
- userId `(int)` - foreign key table_users
- lessonId `(int)` - foreigg key lessons
- dateOfLesson `(datetime)`

And your query, if you're using mysql and you want all date where a user was to lesson, will be:

```
select dateOfLesson, lessons.name as lessonName, table_users.name = userName
from users_lessons_date uld
join table_users u on ( uld.userId = u.id )
join lessons l on (uld.lessonId = l.id)
```